# Segmentation in an image with a single object in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

Here is the  picture:
[image: Bird]

My goal is placing this bird in another image. I tried something with MATLAB, first `rgb2gray` then `imhist` to get the bird intensity, then I made a mask, but I always ended up with a mask which included the tree and the clouds.

Comment: Photoshop may be a good solution. Or GIMP if you want something free.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some code you can use for this task:

```
clear;
close all;
im = imread('~/Downloads/siraly_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg');
im = rgb2gray(im);

%// Manually crop the image
im = double(im(620:1619, 2150:3279));
%// Find edges
hedge = vision.EdgeDetector('Method', 'Sobel');
edges = step(hedge, im);
%// Dilate to close edges around object
edges = imdilate(edges, [0 1 0; 1 1 1; 0 1 0]);
%// Find boundary of object
bound = bwboundaries(edges);
bound = bound{1}; % Largest boundary is around object
%// Display image and object boundary
figure; imshow(im, []);
hold on;
plot(bound(:,2), bound(:,1), '.');
hold off;
%// Select all object pixels by filling the boundary
bwobject = false(size(im));
bwobject(sub2ind(size(im), bound(:,1), bound(:,2))) = true;
bwobject = imfill(bwobject, 'holes');
imobject = zeros(size(im));
imobject(bwobject) = im(bwobject);
figure; imshow(imobject, []);
```

The method used here is:

1. Manual cropping of the image.
2. Edge detection using the [EdgeDetector object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.edgedetector-class.html).
3. Morphological operations to retrieve the object pixels only using [`imdilate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html), [`bwboundaries`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html) and [`imfill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html).

Here are the object boundaries computed and plotted in the code:
[image: Object with boundaries]

And here is the object cropped from the image:
[image: Object cropped]